# Maximizing the smell of coffee in the morning

Tags: evaporation

I bring coffee in a partially filled thermos. The hot coffee evaporates a bit into the cushion of air between the coffee and the lid, the air + coffee vapor mix heats up by heat exchange with the liquid coffee and the pressure increases accordingly. So when I open the lid the pressurized hot air + coffee vapor mix escapes with a delicious sound and even more delicious smell.

I'd like to maximize the amount of coffee vapor that escapes when the lid is open by filling with coffee the optimal percentage of the thermos. Given that air is compressible and the percentage of coffee in the mix may vary, I should probably clarify the objective: to maximize the mole count of the coffee molecules that escape from the thermos the moment the lid is open. Enough time passes between filling the thermos and opening the lid to achieve equilibrium inside the thermos.

Thus the question: what percentage of thermos should be filled by hot coffee to maximize the smell of coffee in the room?

Comment: You can cheat by agitating the coffee, for instance, by swirling it around, or by intermittently replacing the lid and shaking it.

Comment: This does seem more suited to [cooking.se]

Answer (score 0):

If you want instant gratification, put just enough coffee in so that it provides enough vapor to saturate the air in the thermos, and just enough heat to create a bit of pressure.

If you want a good smell over a longer time, fill the thermos. Let the hot coffee continue to fill the room over time. Put a fan on it to spread the joy around.